# htaccess reqwrite rule is redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have this rewrite rule in my htaccess file stored in the root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.domain.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.uk/subdomains/portal/$1 [L,NC]
```

but its redirecting when i dont want it to.

ive tried using `[l,NC,QSA]` too as the flags, but its still redirecting to `domain.com/subdomains/portal`

is there a way i can stop it from redirecting the browser and just keep it mapped to this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Apache sees that the substitution string of the rewriterule is a **different URL** than the one the user browsed to. One is a subdomain and the other is main domain. Because of that, apache will automatically do a 301 redirect even if you don't have the `R flag` there. That is by design. If you want to keep the current URL but get the content of that URL you will have to `proxypass` to it. You can easily do this using the [P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) in the RewriteRule.

Try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.domain.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.uk/subdomains/portal/$1 [P]
```

If it's not working, make sure you have `mod_proxy` enabled.

Comment: I will try that.  How do I enable mod_proxy?

Comment: It depends what server you are on. Ubuntu, Centos etc. There are commands to run or you can uncomment in the apache config.